# Как правильно подключается dashboard (bootstrap) в Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте уважаемые.

***ПРЕДИСЛОВИЕ: я знаю что не все любят читать длинные тексты, но очень вас прошу пожалуйста прочитайте и по возможности помогите решить проблему, она поможет многим воодушевится в веб разработке. С уважением Артур***

**Описание:** *я только сейчас вылез из долгих обучений ruby и наконец добрался до фреймворка  Rails. Я уже имею небольшое представление о технологии MVC и думаю смогу бэккэндить хотя бы костыли, тем самым медленными шагами практиковать и запоминать важные вещи, касательно этого фреймворка.*
Сейчас я столкнулся с неприятной стеной которая медленно разрушает мою уверенность в себе и **прошу вас помочь мне 1 раз разобраться/ подсказать/показать как правильно подключается готовый шаблон на бутстрапе к рельсам**

**КОРОТКО В ДВЕ СТРОКИ О СВОЕЙ ПРОБЛЕМЕ:**
Хочу просто натянуть готовый шаблон бутстрапа на рельсовое приложение. В момент подключение шаблона и запуска rails server у меня не подключаются папки fonts bootstrap  и другие важные составляющие шаблона.

**ШАГ ЗА ШАГОМ ЧТО И КАК Я ДЕЛАЛ:**

Использую программу RubyMine

**1** - Нашёл основу моего будущего проекта: Шаблон ADMINLTE

*ссылки(оф источник):* визуальный вид шаблона https://almsaeedstudio.com

*прямая ссылка на скачивание шаблона(оф источник):* https://almsaeedstudio.com/download/AdminLTE-master

*2* - скачал шаблон

*3* - создаю новое приложение File->new project - > New Application

Ruby SDK: Ruby 2.1.8

Rails Version: 4.2.5.1

**4** - Запускаю bundle install

```
#=>
C:\Users\ruby\RubymineProjects\untitled9>bundle install
Using rake 12.0.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 1.6.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.4
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.4
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using bundler 1.13.7
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.12
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.7.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.4
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sdoc 0.4.2
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.10
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
Using jbuilder 2.6.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
Using railties 4.2.5.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.2.2
Using rails 4.2.5.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using web-console 2.3.0
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**5** - перекидываю все файлы скаченного шаблона ADMINLTE в папку assets в моём рельсовом приложении

перекидывать буду папки такие:

-bootstrap
-build
-dist
-pages
-plugins

**6**
В gemfile добавляю гемы

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'font-awesome-sass'

source 'https://rails-assets.org/' do 
  gem 'rails-assets-adminlte'
end
```

**7** - иду в папку рельсов app/assets/javascripts/application.js и вписываю:

```
//= require adminlte
```

в результате файл стал выглядеть так:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require adminlte
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**8** - иду в рельсах app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

вписываю:

```
*= require adminlte
*= require skin-blue
```

в результате файл стал выглядеть так:

```
/*
 *= require adminlte
 *= require skin-blue
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**9** - Создаю новый файл в рельсах app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss и подключаю туда:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
```

**10** - Теперь из шаблона ADMINLTE я из пути dist/css/skin забираю файл с название skin-blue.css и закидываю его в директорию рельс assets/stylesheets/

**11** - Теперь из шаблона ADMINLTE я открываю исходный код файла с название starter.html и забираю от туда только тело BODY и всё что между ним находится

и всё это переношу в файл рельс app/views/layouts/application.html.erb естественно вставляю только туда где должно быть тело:
Так же заранее скажу что контейнер body я немного изменил добавив туда такое содержание(

`<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">`

) и файл app/views/layouts/application.html.erb выглядит так:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Untitled9</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body class="skin-blue sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Main Header -->
  <header class="main-header">

    <!-- Logo -->
    <a href="index2.html" class="logo">
      <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
      <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
      <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
      <span class="logo-lg"><b>Admin</b>LTE</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Header Navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
      <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
      <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      </a>
      <!-- Navbar Right Menu -->
      <div class="navbar-custom-menu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <!-- Messages: style can be found in dropdown.less-->
          <li class="dropdown messages-menu">
            <!-- Menu toggle button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-success">4</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 4 messages</li>
              <li>
                <!-- inner menu: contains the messages -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- start message -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <div class="pull-left">
                        <!-- User Image -->
                        <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
                      </div>
                      <!-- Message title and timestamp -->
                      <h4>
                        Support Team
                        <small><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 5 mins</small>
                      </h4>
                      <!-- The message -->
                      <p>Why not buy a new awesome theme?</p>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end message -->
                </ul>
                <!-- /.menu -->
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">See All Messages</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- /.messages-menu -->

          <!-- Notifications Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown notifications-menu">
            <!-- Menu toggle button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-bell-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-warning">10</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 10 notifications</li>
              <li>
                <!-- Inner Menu: contains the notifications -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- start notification -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <i class="fa fa-users text-aqua"></i> 5 new members joined today
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end notification -->
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer"><a href="#">View all</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Tasks Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown tasks-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <i class="fa fa-flag-o"></i>
              <span class="label label-danger">9</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li class="header">You have 9 tasks</li>
              <li>
                <!-- Inner menu: contains the tasks -->
                <ul class="menu">
                  <li><!-- Task item -->
                    <a href="#">
                      <!-- Task title and progress text -->
                      <h3>
                        Design some buttons
                        <small class="pull-right">20%</small>
                      </h3>
                      <!-- The progress bar -->
                      <div class="progress xs">
                        <!-- Change the css width attribute to simulate progress -->
                        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-aqua" style="width: 20%" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
                          <span class="sr-only">20% Complete</span>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- end task item -->
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="footer">
                <a href="#">View all tasks</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- User Account Menu -->
          <li class="dropdown user user-menu">
            <!-- Menu Toggle Button -->
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              <!-- The user image in the navbar-->
              <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="user-image" alt="User Image">
              <!-- hidden-xs hides the username on small devices so only the image appears. -->
              <span class="hidden-xs">Alexander Pierce</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <!-- The user image in the menu -->
              <li class="user-header">
                <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">

                <p>
                  Alexander Pierce - Web Developer
                  <small>Member since Nov. 2012</small>
                </p>
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Body -->
              <li class="user-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Followers</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Sales</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xs-4 text-center">
                    <a href="#">Friends</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
              </li>
              <!-- Menu Footer-->
              <li class="user-footer">
                <div class="pull-left">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="pull-right">
                  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-flat">Sign out</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!-- Control Sidebar Toggle Button -->
          <li>
            <a href="#" data-toggle="control-sidebar"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar">

    <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
    <section class="sidebar">

      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel">
        <div class="pull-left image">
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="pull-left info">
          <p>Alexander Pierce</p>
          <!-- Status -->
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle text-success"></i> Online</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- search form (Optional) -->
      <form action="#" method="get" class="sidebar-form">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="submit" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                </button>
              </span>
        </div>
      </form>
      <!-- /.search form -->

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">HEADER</li>
        <!-- Optionally, you can add icons to the links -->
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Link</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Another Link</span></a></li>
        <li class="treeview">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-link"></i> <span>Multilevel</span>
            <span class="pull-right-container">
              <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class="treeview-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link in level 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </section>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <section class="content-header">
      <h1>
        <%= yield %>
      </h1>
      <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Level</a></li>
        <li class="active">Here</li>
      </ol>
    </section>

    <!-- Main content -->
    <section class="content">

      <!-- Your Page Content Here -->

    </section>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <!-- Main Footer -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <!-- To the right -->
    <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
      Anything you want
    </div>
    <!-- Default to the left -->
    <strong>Copyright &copy; 2016 <a href="#">Company</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
  </footer>

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Create the tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified control-sidebar-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a href="#control-sidebar-home-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="#control-sidebar-settings-tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-gears"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
      <!-- Home tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="control-sidebar-home-tab">
        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Recent Activity</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript::;">
              <i class="menu-icon fa fa-birthday-cake bg-red"></i>

              <div class="menu-info">
                <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">Langdon's Birthday</h4>

                <p>Will be 23 on April 24th</p>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

        <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">Tasks Progress</h3>
        <ul class="control-sidebar-menu">
          <li>
            <a href="javascript::;">
              <h4 class="control-sidebar-subheading">
                Custom Template Design
                <span class="pull-right-container">
                  <span class="label label-danger pull-right">70%</span>
                </span>
              </h4>

              <div class="progress progress-xxs">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger" style="width: 70%"></div>
              </div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.control-sidebar-menu -->

      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Stats tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-stats-tab">Stats Tab Content</div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
      <!-- Settings tab content -->
      <div class="tab-pane" id="control-sidebar-settings-tab">
        <form method="post">
          <h3 class="control-sidebar-heading">General Settings</h3>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-sidebar-subheading">
              Report panel usage
              <input type="checkbox" class="pull-right" checked>
            </label>

            <p>
              Some information about this general settings option
            </p>
          </div>
          <!-- /.form-group -->
        </form>
      </div>
      <!-- /.tab-pane -->
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  <!-- Add the sidebar's background. This div must be placed
       immediately after the control sidebar -->
  <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED JS SCRIPTS -->

<!-- jQuery 2.2.3 -->
<script src="plugins/jQuery/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.6 -->
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- AdminLTE App -->
<script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

**11** - запускаю bundle install

```
C:\Users\ruby\RubymineProjects\untitled9>bundle install
Using rake 12.0.0
Using i18n 0.7.0
Using json 1.8.3
Using minitest 5.10.1
Using thread_safe 0.3.5
Using builder 3.2.2
Using erubis 2.7.0
Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
Using rack 1.6.5
Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
Using arel 6.0.4
Using debug_inspector 0.0.2
Using byebug 9.0.6
Using coffee-script-source 1.12.2
Using execjs 2.7.0
Using thor 0.19.4
Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.4
Using multi_json 1.12.1
Using bundler 1.13.7
Using rdoc 4.3.0
Using sass 3.4.23
Using tilt 2.0.5
Using sqlite3 1.3.12
Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
Using tzinfo 1.2.2
Using nokogiri 1.7.0
Using rack-test 0.6.3
Using mime-types 3.1
Using binding_of_caller 0.7.2
Using coffee-script 2.4.1
Using uglifier 3.0.4
Using sprockets 3.7.1
Using sdoc 0.4.2
Using turbolinks 5.0.1
Using activesupport 4.2.5.1
Using tzinfo-data 1.2016.10
Using loofah 2.0.3
Using mail 2.6.4
Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
Using globalid 0.3.7
Using activemodel 4.2.5.1
Using jbuilder 2.6.1
Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.8
Using activejob 4.2.5.1
Using activerecord 4.2.5.1
Using actionview 4.2.5.1
Using actionpack 4.2.5.1
Using actionmailer 4.2.5.1
Using railties 4.2.5.1
Using sprockets-rails 3.2.0
Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
Using jquery-rails 4.2.2
Using rails 4.2.5.1
Using sass-rails 5.0.6
Using web-console 2.3.0
Bundle complete! 12 Gemfile dependencies, 56 gems now installed.
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**12** - создаю контроллер home, rails g controller home

**13** - создаю в котроллере метод index

```
def index
end
```

**14** - создаю вьюху index.html.erb

**15** - прокладываю маршрут в routs

```
root "home#index"
```

**16** - стартую сервер rails s

**17** - захожу в браузер по адресу localhost:3000 и получаю ошибку:

```
Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#index

Showing C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

couldn't find file 'adminlte' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/bootstrap
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/build
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/dist
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/images
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/pages
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/plugins
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/app/assets/stylesheets
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/jquery-rails-4.2.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/coffee-rails-4.1.1/lib/assets/javascripts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/turbolinks-source-5.0.0/lib/assets/javascripts

Rails.root: C:/Users/ruby/RubymineProjects/untitled9
```

**18** - Странно раньше ошибки этой небыло ( Раньше папки бутстрапа fonts img  и другие отдавали в консоле 404.

Answer (score 1):

Убираем:

```
require_tree .
```

И:

```
*= require_tree .
*= require_self
```

Создаем персональные файлы стилей и скриптов для каждого контроллера. Подключаем их в слое. Типа `home.scss` и `home.coffee`. Но тут имя контроллера используется, так что все понятно.

Далее прописываем их в: `/config/initializers/assets.rb`

Идем далее. Об этом речь идет даже на страницах Bootstrap'а. У вас не должно быть файла `application` с расширением `.css`. Только `.scss`. Вы тут имеете дело с SCSS (SASS) и CoffeeScript. По идее - для вашего же удобства. Но это не означает что вы не имеете права писать на обычном CSS и JS - делайте что хотите.

Я считаю, что если вы по изучаете и приведете файлы и код своего проекта к тому, что я привел выше, то у вас ошибка исчезнет сама собой.

*P. S. И текста правда много. Я весь его не читал, но код ваш просмотрел. По сути читал только ваш код и ошибки. Также текст ошибок, который вы привели, сто раз мелькал как на этом сайте, так и на других похожих. Учитесь пользоваться гуглом.*

Comment: *У вас не должно быть файла application с расширением `.css`. Только `.scss`.* -- с чего это вдруг?